# stackexchange site for free blogging in physics

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the possibility of a Physics.SE blog?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/whats-the-possibility-of-a-physics-se-blog)

i recommend to open a site for free blogging in physics
for example:
physics-blogs.stackexchange.com
or
physics-blogger.stackexchange.com
or
physics-blogging.stackexchange.com
...etc

I've searched the whole internet but can not find a suitable site to blogging in physics.
i try to test wordpress and blogspot they are Too Complicated!. Furthermore, there are no reader!