# how do we submit articles for physics.SE blog?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

the title says it all really. I know other SE sites are using the blog feature, but i don't understand yet what is the process for submission of articles. I don't see a physics blog site anywhere so i assume that needs to be deployed first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a Physics SE blog, and you can't really submit articles to something that doesn't exist ;-) So there is no way (for now).

The possibility of starting a site blog has been [previously discussed](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/whats-the-possibility-of-a-physics-se-blog) but there was not enough support for it.

Comment: The corollary is that more interest is the first step.

Comment: assuming there existed one, would someone review the articles before publishing? Do we need volunteers for reviewal and authorship?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about how it works on other sites, but I think there would be some small group of users who are editors (not necessarily the same as the site moderators), and they are the ones who review submissions and actually post them. But anyone from the site can offer to write. Right now the site blogs use Wordpress so you can look into how that works.

Comment: And (@lurscher) yes, we would need volunteers to review and write in order to show that a community blog has enough support to get off the ground. I suppose that could be done with a meta question for "Who would be interested in writing for, or editing, a site blog?" Or something to that effect.

Comment: the editors need to be in a position to validate the scientific validity of the articles, or they are supposed only to validate that they are well-written, etc, it should have some amount of peer-review?

Comment: @lurscher That's probably a decision that can be made by each individual community. Personally I would say the editors should not be expected to perform a full peer review as is done for a journal article, but only to check for basic "sensibleness."